# PHP fgetcsv generated associative array key error

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I just wrote a php function which will read data from a csv file and store the data into an  array with each row data as an element. Each element is an associative array keyed by csv headers.

The function looks like this:

```
function parse_csv($csv_path) {

    if(is_file($csv_path)&&file_exists($csv_path)) {
        $csv_data = array();
        $csv_header = array();
        $n = 0;
        try {
            $csv_file = fopen($csv_path, "r");
            while (!feof($csv_file)) {
                $csv_line = fgetcsv($csv_file); 
                if(array(NULL) !== $csv_line && !empty($csv_line)) {
                    $n++;
                    if($n == 1) {
                        $csv_header = $csv_line;
                    }
                    else {
                        $csv_row = array();
                        for($i=0;$i<count($csv_header);$i++) {
                            $csv_row[$csv_header[$i]] = $csv_line[$i];
                        }
                        $csv_data[] = $csv_row;
                    }
                }
            }

            return $csv_data;
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
    else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

I've done a test and used print_r to print the array ruturned by the function, like the following:

```
$csv = parse_csv('D:\countries.csv');
print_r($csv);
```

The output is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [TermName] => Afghanistan
            [TermDescription] => 
            [TermFormat] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [TermName] => Albania
            [TermDescription] => 
            [TermFormat] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [TermName] => Algeria
            [TermDescription] => 
            [TermFormat] => 
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [TermName] => American Samoa
            [TermDescription] => 
            [TermFormat] => 
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [TermName] => Andorra
            [TermDescription] => 
            [TermFormat] => 
        )
)
```

But when I tried to access the individual element like this

```
print($csv[1]["TermName"]);
```

I got the error: Undefined index: TermName in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\test.php on line 49.

This really confuses me. Am I missing something?

**Found the reason:**

Because I save the csv file with Windows notepad, it added BOM to the file. So the first header becomes to [BOM]TermName. After remove the BOM, it's all good now.

Comment: can you paste more code?

Comment: You are missing the code you tried. Please paste it.

Comment: Just added the function code, thanks guys.

Comment: please check my answer and test your csv file with this function. there is no reason why your array is not accessable with the code you serv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can short your code and make it more readable to find errors faster like this.

```
function parse_csv($csv_path) {

    if(is_file($csv_path) && file_exists($csv_path)) {

        $stream = fopen($csv_path, 'r');
        $csvHeader = fgetcsv($stream);
        $csvData = [];
        while(!feof($stream))
        {
            $lineData = [];
            $line = fgetcsv($stream);

            if( count($csvHeader) != count($line) )
            {
                throw new \Exception('Line '.count($csvData)+1.' got more data then headers!');
            }

            foreach($csvHeader as $x => $header)
            {
                $lineData[$header] = $line[$x];
            }

            $csvData[] = $lineData;
        }
        return $csvData;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Hi ins0, tested the function. The error was still the same. That's strange.

Comment: very stange, please post your full code how you test the function

Comment: The function code is exactly the same as you posted. The calling is just $csv = parse_csv('D:\countries.csv');print($csv[0]['TermName']); which returns error: Notice: Undefined index: TermName in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\test.php on line 78

Comment: maybe mixing two different charsets - csv charset and php charset different as you declare your key over the csv file, but this can't be the error

Comment: Thanks ins0. Finally figured out it's the BOM of the csv file. So the key 'TermName' was appended with a prefix. After remove the BOM, it works as expected.